# not converting the int into a string on if statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an int into a str using a if loop! here is my logiv. What is it that I am doing wrong ? Any ideas ?

```
var waitTime  = parseInt("53");
if (waitTime > 20) {
  return 'a lot of time'
} else if (waitTime < 20) {
  return 'we can wait'
}

console.log(waitTime);
```

I keep getting

Comment: You are using `return` statements but you have not declared or created a function here?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks mostly correct, including your usage of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), but perhaps you are mixing your `return` statements with `console.log` statements?

```
var waitTime = parseInt("53");    
if (waitTime > 20) {    
    console.log('a lot of time'); // use console.log rather than return
} else if (waitTime < 20) {    
    console.log('we can wait'); // use console.log rather than return
}

console.log(waitTime);
```

http://jsbin.com/kebagodura/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response ! You were right i got mixed up with Python and used return instead of console log.

Comment: Your output:
a lot of time
53
Correct output:
a lot of time

Comment: @MarioGomez you were getting the error because without being inside a function, using `return`  will cause a runtime error. If you are just within the global scope there is nothing to return, so an error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (to Jonathan's answer), put the code in a function and then the `return`s would make sense. An improved version would see you passing in the wait time as an argument to the function.

```
function doIt(number) {

  // Don't forget the radix on parseInt
  var waitTime  = parseInt(number, 10);
  if (waitTime > 20) {
    return 'a lot of time'
  } else if (waitTime < 20) {
    return 'we can wait'
  }
}

var result = doIt('53'); // a lot of time
var result = doIt('12'); // we can wait
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xuxhbrz1/2/)

Comment: Thanks !! Makes sense as a function

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code.

```
return 'a lot of time'
```

It is trying to return the text `a lot of time` from a function. but you never created a function so it will throw an error.

**Closer to what you want:**

```
function wait(waitTime) {
  if (waitTime > 20) {
    return 'a lot of time'
  } else if (waitTime < 20) {
    return 'we can wait'
  }
}
console.log(wait(YOUR_WAIT_TIME_HERE));
```

**EDIT** You don't need the `parseInt` function at all. (ie: `'25' > 20`) implicitly casts `'25'` to a `Number`.

Comment: If you're passing in a value for `waitTime` why are you declaring it again in the function. And shouldn't you be passing in a string, not `waitTime`?

Comment: was a typo @Andy , thnks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply can do that this way, reassigning the variable values in the if/else clause:

```js
var waitTime = parseInt("53");

if (waitTime > 20) {
   waitTime = 'a lot of time';
} else if (waitTime <= 20) {
   waitTime = 'we can wait';
}

console.log(waitTime);
```

Comment: Thanks! Since my class is very basic I ended using this version ! I modified it a little bit because I realized when I was using 20 it returned NaN.

Comment: re: your jsbin: for some reason I never succeed to open jsbins, also not yours - do you have to be registered there to be allowed to see it?

Comment: For clarity you might think about using a different variable name for the messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way- instead of "return" you can do this:

```
var waitTime  = parseInt("53");
if (waitTime > 20) {
  waitTime = 'a lot of time';
} else if (waitTime < 20) {
  waitTime = 'we can wait';
}

console.log(waitTime);
```

Comment: For clarity you might think about using a different variable name for the messages.

Comment: Thanks! I ended out doing something similar